# Количество строк

Tags: delphi, pascal

В текстовом файле посчитать количество строк, которые начинаются и кончаются одной и той же согласной буквой. Прошу помочь с этой программой.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi:

```
var i,n:integer;s:string;
begin
n:=0;
Memo1.lines.LoadFromFile('1.txt');
for i:=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
   begin
   s:=Memo1.Lines[i];
   if (s[1]='Согласная') and (s[Length(s)]='Согласная') then
     inc(n);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Это как?

Comment: Это полностью?

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм простой тут:

1. Читаете очередную строку;
2. Переводите её в один регистр - например, в верхний;
3. Смотрите первую букву - если она не согласная (для этого должен быть список согласных букв, с коими и сравнивать надо поочерёдно), то идём на начало, в пункт 1;
4. Ищется последняя буква и сравнивается с первой. Если совпадает - прибавляем к счётчику один.